# SQL query to group multiple values

Tags: sql, oracle

Can you let me how to build sql query for the below requirement:
I have 2 tables:

**Table A:**

```
col1 | Col2
------------
1    | a
2    | b
```

**Table B:**

```
Col1 | Col2
-----------
1    | 10
2    | 20
a    | 30
b    | 40
```

I need output like this:

```
Col1 | Col2
------------
1,a  | 10,30
2,b  | 20,40
```

Can anyone one help me please. Thanks

Comment: Please add to your question the exact logic used to produce the result.

Comment: Hello, I am asking for logic to derive the output. I need output with comma separated. How to join these two tables(A & B) to get required output ?

Comment: Then provide a larger example with more use cases.

Comment: which database?

Comment: Oracle DB .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(t1.col1, ' , ', t2.col1) AS Col1, CONCAT(t1.col2, ' , ', t2.col2) AS Col2
from
(select t1.col1, t2.col2 from tableA t1, tableB t2
where t1.col1 = t2.col1) as t1,
(select t1.col1 as col3, t2.col1, t2.col2 from tableA t1, tableB t2
where t1.col2 = t2.col1) as t2
where t1.col1 = t2.col3;
```

SQL Fiddle here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/459ae69/25

Comment: This assume exist only pairs. If you have one aditional element you will have unnecesary rows. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd20cc/1 also OP db is oracle

Answer (score 0):

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/02a43/5)**

```
SELECT  CONCAT(CONCAT(A."Col1", ' , '), A."Col2") AS Col1, 
        LISTAGG(B."Col2", ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY B."Col1") Col2
FROM TableA A
JOIN TableB B
  ON A."Col1" = B."Col1"
  OR A."Col2" = B."Col1"
GROUP BY CONCAT(CONCAT(A."Col1", ' , '), A."Col2")  
  ;
```

OUTPUT

```
|  COL1 |   COL2 |
|-------|--------|
| 1 , a | 10, 30 |
| 2 , b | 20, 40 |
```